# Concisely describe non-time sensitive measurements

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I am working on profiling a graphical PC application. In this context, profiling is the act of taking measurements, mostly time based (like "time elapsed while rendering x"), but also some simple values (like "the number of x used" where x is not a unit of time).

Multiple of "the same" measurements are taken by running the same simulation multiple times. Because recording the simple values has an impact on time, I take "time" and "value" measurements in separate runs. I would like to name these two types of profiling.

Can you think of a more concise wording of "Non Time Sensitive Profiling".  In the context of programming "NonTimeSensitiveProfiling" is a bit long. A compound word or phrase is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Atemporal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atemporal) means "independent of time".  I've seen "atemporal measurement" used in technical writing to describe something with which time does not affect. "Atemporal Profiling" would be something that you would need to define through a context menu to describe to a user exactly what is meant by the term.

Answer (score 0):

While [JRodge01](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/361344/jrodge01) is right about *atemporal*, it suggests a dichotomy: time-based measurements and everything else. So you would be painting yourself into a corner, and couldn't in the future add a third category.

Since technical writing strives to be clear, rather than didactic, I think you have already answered your question: non time-sensitive measurements should be **value** measurements.

Then some day you could have TimeProfiling, ValueProfiling, PresenceProfiling, UnobservedProfiling, NagiosFlappingProfiling, and so on.

Comment: Aren't durations are also values? I was looking for a better word than value because value seemed to vague. The introduced dichotomy is appropriate for my use-case but thank you for making me aware.

Comment: Perhaps **Event**, **DiscreteEvent**, or **Occurrence** would make it clear that you are measuring only whether or not something has happened.

Comment: I am not recording spurious events. Atemporal is appropriate.